# In clean architecture, How to do acceptance testing?

Tags: android, fitnesse, acceptance-testing, clean-architecture

In Android, I'm using clean architecture and putting my code packaged by layer. So I've 4 layers **(modules)** :

- app
- data
- device
- domain

I know, correct me if I'm wrong, that acceptance testing **(Using FitNesse)** should replace UI in better words, it should mimic UI and test core functions of the system from customer's point of view.

My Question is :

**Should I** create another module for FitNesse fixtures and stuff, with dependencies on each module in the system?

Comment: Don't you (also or even only) want the acceptance test to test the GUI? That's what your users will use after all.

Comment: He's got it right.  Fitnesse like Cucumber is a tool designed to test business logic by calling the code of the system under test directly, independent of UI.  End to end testing through UI is sweet spot of different tools such as WebDriver APIs to drive browsers.  Business logic is best tested away from UI since UIs tend to change a lot, and also require application deployment somewhere to test, and respond much more slowly since you are testing over wire.

Comment: sorry, for being late.
@FriedHoeben > No I don't want acceptance testing to test the UI.

Comment: I tend to use FitNesse to test on various levels, both on services and against UI (using WebDriver API in fixture code), but always after the code has been deployed. For tests directly against the code, without deployment I tend to favour unit testing tools (like jUnit, TestNG, etc). The added value of tests via a wiki when your working directly against code seems minimal to me.

Comment: in a nutshell, you say that:
    
    1. we should use Acceptance testing framework after deployment.
    2. Use unit testing frameworks before that. 
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I usually see done, yes.  The builder system (maven, gradle, etc.) is tweaked so that it does not include the module containing the fixtures in the production artifact.  The module containing the fitnesse fixtures is aware of / has dependencies to all of the modules it directly tests, which tends to be the domain layer.

Comment: I also tend to use this approach with a separate module. At which level the tests connect to the system under test is something we could debate, but that was not the main question.